# Align currently floated div to bottom without changing HTML

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

### Problem

I have a header with the basic HTML structure

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="navigation"></div>
  <div id="userInfo"></div>
  <div class="headRight"></div>
  <div id="callCenter" class="headRight"></div>
</div>
```

I cannot change the HTML. Currently it is laid out with floats, and `navigation` was aligned to the bottom of the header using `padding-top`. However, it only works when `userInfo` is 2 lines, and it can be 3 or 4.

### What I need to do

Using only CSS, align `navigation` to the bottom for all nav heights while maintaining the original layout.

### What I've tried

Half a dozen stack overflow solutions including the classics `position:absolute` and `vertical-align:bottom` on parent. (The former breaks the document flow, and the latter seems not to work because other elements get in the way.)

### The fiddle

Cleaned fiddle best I could, but inspect will probably still be easiest.
https://jsfiddle.net/ohrhe4u5/1/

Notes:

1. The tabs should just touch the bottom of the header.
2. `callCenter` is misaligned in this example as well, but you can ignore. It's much lower priority.

### New fiddle

I changed `header`, `logo`, and `navigation` to `display:inline-block`, allowed `userInfo` to float right, gave the nave extra height to make sure there's always room, and absolute positioned the `headRight` items.

That leaves me with this. A little janky due to the absolute positioning and forcing the nav height larger. Any better ideas?
https://jsfiddle.net/ohrhe4u5/2/

Comment: Floated elements are always "on the top", you can not align them to the bottom. Go look into flexbox' `order` property instead.

Comment: It is okay (agreed, probably necessary) to use something other than float to keep the layout. However, I believe I need to support down to IE8 or thereabouts, so no flexbox.

Comment: Well then implement a JS fallback that moves the elements in the DOM, if supporting absolutely outdated security risks is a real concern ...

Comment: No JS changes allowed either. Rough, I know. That's why I'm here.

Comment: Why don't use conditional stylesheets? :)

Comment: I would better keep the question as absurd. If you can't use proper css and styling, and boasting 500 conditions on how it should be done?

Comment: @Deadpool I'm not boasting about conditions, they have been forced on me. This is what real life is like. I respectfully disagree that having a lot of client restrictions makes it a bad question.

Comment: Ok. May be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally dislike `float` for positioning where i can help it (this is a personal preference because i find it sometimes painfully unpredictable), as such, using a combination of `position:absolute`, `min-height` and `margin` i believe i have recreated what you're after.

Basically this solution works by `position:absolute`'ing the elements that we have some idea of consistent sizes of (the logo and the navigation), then have the header element take its `height` from the user data and links on the right. We add a `min-height` to the header element though so that should the user data be reduced to 2 lines, the height is still enough to accommodate the absolutely positioned elements (given they no longer affect the height of the header element by being `absolute`).

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ohrhe4u5/4/)**

**CSS**

```
/* new parts of the css */
#header {
    min-height:112px; /* in case user data is made smaller */
    padding:10px 10px 0 20px;
    position:relative;
}
#logo {
    width: 210px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:210px;
    height:62px;
    left:20px;
    margin-top:-32px;
    z-index:1; /* bring logo above the user data */
}
#navigation {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:210px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 1; /* bring navigation above the user data*/
}
#userInfo table{
    margin:0 0 0 auto;
}
.headRight{
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does seem slightly better than my second fiddle. The `.headRight` items are supposed to stick to the bottom of the nav, so I had to add some extra bottom padding to `#userInfo` to account for the case where `#userInfo` is two lines. If you have an idea for how to actually align them to the bottom that would be great, but it's definitely usable.

Comment: @disso, probably the easiest way is going to be to adjust the `min-height` of the `#header` so that they fit nicely. Without hardcoding the height of your header i dont think there's another solution that works nicely (either a `position:absolute` or `display:table` trick)